# Display image along with text in a cell when in non-edit mode

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

I'm evaluating the Kendo UI Gantt chart to see if it fits our project requirements.

One particular requirement is to display a status column which would be a drop down in edit mode and has three statuses

1. Red 2. Green 3. Yellow, along with an image indicator something like what is shown in the image below

[image]

I am able to achieve the above effect when i edit a cell after using a custom editor for the drop down

```
function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "Status",
                dataValueField: "StatusId",
                valueTemplate: '<img class="selected-value" src="#:data.Url#" alt="#:data.Status#" /><span>#:data.Status#</span>',
                template: '<img class="selected-value" src="#:data.Url#" alt="#:data.Status#" /><span>#:data.Status#</span>',
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: function (e) {
                            // on success
                            e.success([{ Status: 'Not Started', StatusId: '0', Url: 'Image/red.png' }, { Status: 'Red', StatusId: '1', Url: 'Image/red.png' }, { Status: 'Green', StatusId: '2', Url: 'Image/red.png' }, { Status: 'Yellow', StatusId: '3', Url: 'Image/red.png' }]);
                            // on failure
                            //e.error("XHR response", "status code", "error message");
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

The Gantt Column for Status looks like the below snippet

```
{ field: "status", title: "Status", editable: true, width: 150, editor: statusDropDownEditor, template: '<img class="selected-value" src="#:data.Url#" alt="#:data.Status#" /><span>#:data.Status#</span>' }
```

However when done with selecting a particular item from drop down and on exiting the edit mode this is how the cell looks like

[image]

Seems like the default cell template in read only mode does not render html and the invokes the toString of the object bound to the cell, is there a way to fix this in the kendo UI Gantt

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve the same issue today and it looks like gantt columns do not support the template properties.

I have created a new [feature suggestion on the Kendo user feedback site](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/9358875-add-template-support-to-gantt-columns). If enough people vote for it maybe they will implement this.

The only work around I found was to prepend an image tag onto the field column like this. But this solution is not conditional.

```
<div id="gantt"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var gantt = $("#gantt").kendoGantt({
            dataSource: [
              {
                id: 1,
                title: "apples",
                orderId: 0,
                parentId: null,
                start: new Date("2015/1/17"),
                end: new Date("2015/10/17"),
                summary:false,
                expanded:false
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                orderId: 1,
                parentId: null,
                title: "banana",
                start: new Date("2015/1/17"),
                end: new Date("2015/3/17"),
                summary:false,
                expanded:true
              }
            ],
            views: [
                { type: "year", selected: true }
            ],
            columns: [
                { field: "title", title: "fruit", width: 220 },
                { field: "start", title: "start", width: 80 }
            ],
        }).data("kendoGantt");

        $(".k-grid-content tbody[role='rowgroup'] tr[role='row'] td:first-child").prepend("<img href='#' alt='image here'></img>");

    });

</script>
```

The [sample page](https://github.com/Padhraic/Kendo-ui-samples/blob/master/gantt-col-prepend-example.html) is on git.